# I have a loop a prob in my exercice

Tags: java

The velocity is updated every second and I want to print on the console when the velocity exceeds 343 m/s this:

> felix depasse la vitesse du son

It will be printed only ONE time before the velocity exceeds 343.

How can I do this?

When I do this code it will print every time velocity exceeds 343; what condition I can do to make it printed only ONE time?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Parachutiste {

    private static Scanner clavier = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double masse = 80.0;
        do {
            System.out.print("masse du parachutiste (>= 40) ? ");
            masse = clavier.nextDouble();
        } while (masse < 40.0);

        double h0 = 39000.0;
        do {
            System.out.print("hauteur de depart du parachutiste (>= 250) ? ");
            h0 = clavier.nextInt();
        } while (h0 < 250.0);


    double g=9.81;
    double v0=0;
    double t0=0;
    double vitesse=v0;
    double hauteur=h0;
    double accel=g;
    double t=t0;
    double surface=2;
    double q;

    do{

    if(vitesse>343){


        System.out.println("## Felix depasse la vitesse du son");

    }
        double sm=surface/masse;
      q=Math.exp((-sm*(t-t0)));
    vitesse=(g/sm)*(1-q)+(v0*q);
    hauteur = h0-((g/sm)*(t-t0))-((v0-(g/sm))/sm)*(1-q);
    accel=g-(sm*vitesse);
     if(hauteur>0){
            // Utilisez cette ligne pour l'affichage
            System.out.format("%.0f, %.4f, %.4f, %.5f\n",
                              t, hauteur, vitesse, accel);}
            t++;
     }
    while(hauteur>0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to continue `vitesse` computation if the vitesse exceeds 343 ? If not, put a simple `break;` after your println statement. Otherwise, use a boolean condition to find if you have already printed the message.

Comment: when i add break i will be out of the for loop also and when i add boolean it doesn't work

Comment: There is no for loop in your code and the boolean solution is the one you've been given by two other SO members, I think it should work.

Comment: sorry i will be out of the do while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

Declare this outside your loop:

```
boolean isPrinted = false;
```

and then swap this in for your if loop:

```
if(!isPrinted)
    if(vitesse>343) {
        isPrinted = true;
        System.out.println("## Felix depasse la vitesse du son");
    }
}
```

Comment: when i added this code it doesn't work and post "## Felix depasse la vitesse du son" every time velocity>343.

Comment: Did you remove the original if loop and replace it with the block i provided?

Comment: yeah... it may because of the do while loop so time exceeds and the if loop you wrote is repeated every second ?

Comment: Make sure you are declaring your boolean outside of the "main" while loop so it isn't being set to false again.

Answer (score 0):

@Salma you can do this just create a boolean variable and instantiate it with true value and set it as extra condition in side if(vitesse>343) and reset it as false then for different input value it will display only once. Like this

```
at variable declaration  section

boolean bool_once =True

if(vitesse>343 & bool_once){// and condition 
  .....
  .....
 bool_once = False // reset the value
```